# Wordpress: how to count wp_list_pages

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently using 'wp_list_pages' to display child pages within my wordpress website.

Here is my code to display the pages;

```
                wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&show_date=modified&date_format=$date_format&location=sidebar&sort_column=menu_order");
```

This works fine but I want to be able to count the list of results.

How can you count this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use [`get_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) which will return an array

`wp_list_pages` uses `get_pages` to retrieve the data and performs extra formatting

Comment: I've tried adding count($get_pages); but it always return zero even when there are multiple items listed with wp_list_pages.

Comment: have you tried the following? `count(get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID));`

Comment: Hi, I'm having a related trouble, but I need to modify the information, maybe you can take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915993/how-to-change-the-href-in-a-menu-created-by-wp-list-pages

Answer (score 0):

If you're running version 2.8 or above, add the parameter number to the wp_list_pages function.

Seems buggy. Adding number=8, outputs 4 pages.

Its documented here, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages